# Different layout/route for mobile device and desktop in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a lazy module which I want a different experience for desktop and mobile device. Basically I want my desktop layout like:
[image: Desktop layout]

Component1 display a list, user chooses an item on the list and component2 will display the details. I created router-outlet named 'side' to display as a sidebar. Here's is the router config:

```
const desktop_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListComponent,
        outlet: 'side'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'detail',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'detail',
        component: DetailComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
```

In mobile layout, I want Component1 as the content of path: '', user choose any time from the list will be lead to detail page (2 separate page): 
[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same child components but create 2 route lists: `/desktop/component2` and `/mobile/component2`.
Then in desktop parent show `component3a` containing the desktop layout. In mobile layout set the routes up so that `component3a` has a single outlet and loads the pages all into a single `router-outlet`, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another approach. If you know when you're in a "mobile" or in a "desktop" (really you should check the "screen.size"). see, e.g. [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051786/how-can-i-check-screen-resolution-on-an-angular-website/67122073#67122073)

You can has some like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{size:commonService.resize$|async} as size">
  <div #detail *ngIf="size.size?.width>500">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

In your component you try to "get" the div detail

```
@ViewChild('detail') detail:ElementRef<any>
```

know you can check if "detail" exist and navigate to one or another one direction

```
click(){
    if (this.detail)
       this.router.navigate('parent/child/1')
    else
       this.router.navigate('parent-child/1')

}
```

You router definition like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent,children:[
       {path:'child:id', component:ChildrenComponent
   ] },
  { path: 'parent-child:id', component: ChildrenComponent },
];
```

yet you can reach the child-component using `parent-child/1` in the "main" router-outlet or using `parent/child/1` (in the "main" router-outlet you has "parent" and in the router-outlet of "parent" you has the child)