# How can I check screen resolution on an angular website?

Tags: angular, screen-resolution, devextreme, screen-size, devextreme-angular

Is there a way to check screen resolution on an angular website? I have a scenario where an application I'm working on has been designed using DevExtreme default components. This makes it difficult to customize.

In my case I'm dealing with a popup that's a form.  It isn't displaying properly on 1920x1080. I.E. portions of it aren't showing.

*I'm extremely NEW to Angular*

Comment: What would define the popup displaying correctly? Are you able to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example So we can see what you are currently working with!

Comment: I don't have a way to post an example. Just imagine a form that's a popup displaying improperly due to screen resolution changes. Does that help at all Dylan?

Comment: Sorry no my imagination isn't that great, I like to work off the facts and examples so i don't waste my time coming up with a solution to something that woudn't solve your problem.

Comment: Dylan, no worries. I will see if I can get an example.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the browser windows using media query
[check this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Wait. Are you suggesting to do it straight through just CSS?

Comment: Yes , that is media query

Comment: I actually read about this today, but I'm quite stumped on how to use it. Thank you for replying. I appreciate it.

Comment: @OGC0der - don't be discouraged; it is very advanced stuff. Your code shouldn't explicitly check for browser size. **Definitely not** Angular code. You should use libraries like Bootstrap that will take care of adjusting controls for you.

Comment: Felix, I had found a reference to using bootstrap, but wasn't sure if that was overkill if you know what I mean. See here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/detect-responsive-screen-sizes-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.innerHeight or window.innerWidth. Probably you will need a resize method for the screen resize too.

**Update:**

HTML:

```
<div (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
```

TS:

```
   onResize(e){
     //SET SIZE OF THE GRID (calculated)

    var screenHeight= window.innerHeight;
    this.gritContentHeight= screenHeight-150;
   }
```

Comment: Ades, I see. How does that work with a DevExtreme form component though?

Comment: You have the same problem as me in the past! Probably your datagrid not resize or only resize width... You can create a method on resize in a div to detect the event and then bind height and width of the datagrid to a TS var.

Comment: Ades, that sounds great. However, I have no clue how to do what you just explained based off your experience using angular.

Comment: Ades, Awesome. I'll test it out soon and let you know if it works or gets me moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

In general the best bet is using media-querys and display:none. But you can also create a simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs'
import {map,debounceTime,distinctUntilChanged,startWith,tap} from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CommonService {
  resize$=fromEvent(window,'resize').pipe(
      startWith(null),
      debounceTime(100),
      map(_=>{
       if ((window.innerWidth)<576)
        return 'xs'
       if ((window.innerWidth)<768)
        return 'sm'
       if ((window.innerWidth)<992)
        return 'md'
       if ((window.innerWidth)<1200)
        return 'lg'
       if ((window.innerWidth)<1400)
        return 'xl'
       return 'xxl'
    }),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(x=>({size:x,width:window.innerWidth})),
    tap(res=>console.log(res))
    )
  constructor() { }
}
```

You can use in a component that inject the service as public and use, e.g.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{size:commonService.resize$|async} as size">
  <div *ngIf="size.size?.size=='sm'">I'm sm</div>
  <div *ngIf="size.size?.size=='xs'">I'm xs</div>
  <div *ngIf="size.size?.width>500">I'm greater than 500</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Eliseo, This is very similar to a resource I found. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular cdk:

Sometimes we need to know the width of the browser window in our component’s class file. You could have a @HostListener in a component for the window's resize event, but you'd have to maintain the service, write tests to make sure it was working properly, handle observables correctly so there aren't memory leaks, etc. The Angular CDK's LayoutModule has a BreakpointObserver class that you can inject into a component, provide a breakpoint (or breakpoints) that you want to watch for, and it will emit each time you cross the threshold of a breakpoint (i.e. if I want to know when the screen is smaller than 700px, it will emit a value when I cross under 700px, and then again when I cross back over 700px).

```
import { Output, Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ScreenService {
  @Output() changed = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    this.breakpointObserver
      .observe([Breakpoints.XSmall, Breakpoints.Small, Breakpoints.Medium, Breakpoints.Large])
      .subscribe(() => this.changed.next());
  }

  private isLargeScreen() {
    const isLarge = this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.Large);
    const isXLarge = this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.XLarge);

    return isLarge || isXLarge;
  }

  public get sizes() {
    return {
      'screen-x-small': this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.XSmall),
      'screen-small': this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.Small),
      'screen-medium': this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.Medium),
      'screen-large': this.isLargeScreen(),
    };
  }
}
```

And use it to detect screen size to open/close menu for example:

```
this.isMenuOpened = this.screen.sizes['screen-large'];
```

Also detect screen size changes:

```
this.screen.changed.subscribe(() => this.updateForm());
```

Better Explanation is [here](https://medium.com/@pjlamb12/angular-cdks-breakpointobserver-b75df04a1cc2)

Stackblitz Example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pjlamb12-breakpoint-observer-demo)

GitHub Repo is [here](https://github.com/pjlamb12/breakpoint-observer-demo)